# StreamSets CDC origin: Mysql-Binarylog unable to get driver instance

Tags: mysql, cdc, streamsets

I am trying to setup Mysql-BinaryLog in StreamSets, but it complains it cannot load the driver instance.

my.cnf:

```
[mysqld]
    server-id         = 223344
    log_bin           = mysql-bin
    binlog_format     = row
    binlog_row_image  = full
    expire_logs_days  = 10
```

Is there something else it has to be done in order for the StreamSets origin to work ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to [install the MySQL JDBC driver](https://streamsets.com/documentation/datacollector/latest/help/index.html#datacollector/UserGuide/Origins/MySQLBinaryLog.html#concept_wps_52k_qy) into Data Collector - follow the instructions for [installing an external library](https://streamsets.com/documentation/datacollector/latest/help/index.html#datacollector/UserGuide/Configuration/ExternalLibs.html#concept_pdv_qlw_ft), but ensure you select the MySQL BinLog stage library when uploading the JDBC driver:

[image]

Also, if you're using MySQL Server 5.x, please use a version 5.x MySQL JDBC driver. There are known issues trying to use the version 8.x JDBC driver with an older server.